# What could be causing thumping in the wall when the bathroom shower, toilet, or sink are used?

Tags: plumbing, walls, drain, noise

I hear a thumping in the wall whenever the second floor bathroom shower, toilet, or sink are used (sound is similar to if you let the bottom of your fist fall against a sheetrock wall). It is 'almost' at a regular interval. I also don't recall hearing it in the summertime, but have only been in this house for a year. It is related to the drain, because when I put my ear up to the wall where the sound is coming from, I can hear the sound water rushing down the PVC very clearly. Once the water is off, the sound stops. Does anyone know what might be the cause of the sound?

Comment: Is it a clicking/popping sound every few seconds, and more pronounced when you use hot water?

Comment: See [this answer](http://diy.stackexchange.com/a/8482/2196). I should mention that it also applies to drain pipes (e.g. PVC), not just to copper pipes as my comments may imply.

Comment: Hi Chris, it can probably be described as a 'pop' sound, too. It occurs with both hot and cold water—ran the shower with only cold water and it still occurred. It is fairly loud.

Comment: I'm guessing it's expanding pipes, but if the above answer doesn't help, it could also be "water hammer" if it happens when water pressure suddenly changes (open/close quickly) or if it's quicker (a few times per second).

Comment: Could it be a "glugging" sound?  It could be that the vent is clogged (or missing) so instead, one of the other fixtures is acting as a vent.  For example.  Water is going down the shower drain, and using the sink drain as an [air admittance device (AAV)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drain-waste-vent_system#Air_admittance_valve). This might explain a consistent, almost rhythmic sound.

Comment: The "glugging" sound mentioned above, could be amplified by a drain pipe being in contact with drywall in a wall cavity.

Comment: My pipes are constantly hammering, this is when my house is consuming water (ie, dishwasher, shower, basins, etc) the water hammer occurs from the instantaneous shut off of water. at the end i needed to install water hammer arrestors.

Comment: Hm...any chance of a recording of the sound?